# Docear on Kubuntu 12.04 64

Tags: software-installation, kubuntu

I am running a 64bit version of Kubuntu 12.04 and I would like to run [Docear](https://www.docear.org/) (Some kind of research assistant) on it. The software is based on Java (which I had it installed) and has only a `.sh` file which based on their website you just need to double click it to run the software. Every time I double click I just seed the splash screen and then nothing!

Is there anyway to resolve this issue? cause this software can severely ease my burden.

Comment: Try running it from the terminal to see what error message(s) you get and report your findings here.

Comment: There are several versions of Java, which one did you install (which package name)?

Comment: Thanks for your quick respond. Well, it seems I asked a silly question cause the program was running on the background behind all my windows and when I went back to my desktop I saw its set-up window and it shows up in the app list in the task bar. BTW, is there anyway that I can launch Docear using my lovely _Synapse_ instead of going to its directory and double click the sh file?